# Rails Number to Indian currency format conversion helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

i have number like 100000

when i user number_to_currency(100000)

it give - 100,000.00

but how can i get format like 1,00,000.00

as $ 100,000 looks good but to show it in Rs i need separators (',') like this - 1,00,00,000.00

Comment: What does 1,00,00,000.00 mean? Veery strange number, at least for me. It isn't easy readable.

Comment: Indian rupees are formatted in such way e.g. $ 100,000,000 are represented as Rs.10,00,00,000 so..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

checkout http://www.funonrails.com/2011/03/number-to-indian-currency-helper-for.html

```
def number_to_indian_currency(number, html=true)
 txt = html ? content_tag(:span, 'Rs.', :class => :WebRupee) : 'Rs.' 
 "#{txt} #{number.to_s.gsub(/(\d+?)(?=(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))(\.\d+)?/, "\\1,")}"
 end
```

Comment: there is gem release of it `number_to_indian_currency` which supports `formatting` as well as `css for rupee symbol`

Answer (score 2):

[RubyMoney](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) has a formatting option for south Asia (can be used for India as well).

```
def number_to_indian_rupee(rupees)
  Money.new(rupees, "INR").format(south_asian_number_formatting: true)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def number_to_indian_currency(number)
  if number.present?
    string = number.to_s.split('.')
    number = string[0].gsub(/(\d+)(\d{3})$/){ p = $2;"#{$1.reverse.gsub(/(\d{2})/,'\1,').reverse},#{p}"}
    number = number.gsub(/^,/, '') + '.' + string[1] if string[1] # remove leading comma
    number = number[1..-1] if number[0] == 44
  end
  "Rs.#{number}"
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing your own function to perform this display formatting, rather than overwriting number_to_currency.  You could call it r_number_to_currency or something like that and place it in your application view helper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Pan, I wrote a helper for that...

Something like this -

```
def rupees_helper(number)
      number = number.to_s
      rs = ""
      number.reverse.chars.each_with_index{|i, index| rs<<i; rs<<"," if index==2; rs<<"," if (index!=number.chars.count-1&&index>3&&index%2==0) }
      rs = rs.reverse
      return "Rs. " + rs
  end
```

which on passing 1000000 gives me "Rs 10,00,000"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_to_indian_currency(number) 
    if number string = number.to_s.split('.') 
     number = string[0].gsub(/(\d+)(\d{3})$/){ p = $2;"#{$1.reverse.gsub(/(\d{2})/,'\1,').reverse},#{p}"} 
     number = number.gsub(/^,/, '') + '.' + string[1] if string[1] # remove leading comma 
     number = number[1..-1] if number[0] == 44  
    end 
   "Rs.#{number}" 
end
```

Sample Output for different combinations

```
  helper.number_to_indian_currency(2000)=> “Rs.2,000”

  helper.number_to_indian_currency(2040)=> “Rs.2,040”

  helper.number_to_indian_currency(1222040.54)=> “Rs.12,22,040.54”
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is this line for? `number = number[1..-1] if number[0] == 44`.